# CSS3 (or jQuery) Change Content Sequence

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I've found this great snippet. Would it be possible to show a sequence? Like 1,2,3,4 and so on?

http://jsfiddle.net/G9LKK/

```
.item a p.new-label span{
  position: relative;
  content: 'NEW'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS won't do it, as it has no capacity for math. It's easy in jQuery, though:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/vpk5r/

```
var i = 1;

$('.item a p.new-label span').each(function() {
    $(this).text(i);
    i++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [**`Fiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/G9LKK/5/)...

This will dynamically change the value ap per your desired order and also this definetly creates a idea to your requirement...

Comment: Yes, this is what I've tried. Would it be possible to change the 1,2,3 and so on with Webfont Icons?